# Installing flask-bcrypt; not finishing and stuck at Running setup.py install for bcrypt

Tags: flask, pip, bcrypt

I have been trying to install flask-bcrypt so far, but every time I tried it gets stuck at 'Running setup.py install for bcrypt'

It starts correctly, I suppoase as below.

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): flask-bcrypt in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask_Bcrypt-0.7.1-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from flask-bcrypt)
Collecting bcrypt (from flask-bcrypt)
  Downloading bcrypt-2.0.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Werkzeug>=0.7 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask->flask-bcrypt)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Jinja2>=2.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask->flask-bcrypt)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): itsdangerous>=0.21 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Flask->flask-bcrypt)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cffi>=1.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from bcrypt->flask-bcrypt)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.4.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from bcrypt->flask-bcrypt)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MarkupSafe in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->Flask->flask-bcrypt)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycparser in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.1->bcrypt->flask-bcrypt)
Installing collected packages: bcrypt
  Running setup.py install for bcrypt
```

-> from here it is not being finished. 
I have installed flask extension such as login, bootstrap, wtf. All of them were successful, but bcrypt. I have used pip to install and tried with easy_isntall as well, nothing worked.

I am not sure what I am missing here. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

EDIT)
Thanks Joe for the suggestion. But it seems like it gets stuck again as below.

```
Running command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-_9RHUo/bcrypt/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-oEbDb0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
```

Could you explain what -v does?

Comment: Can you please add `-v` to pip install?

Comment: Do you see some activity in the process manager (e.g. with `top` in Linux) during the install? Bcrypt has to compile some files, maybe it just needs more time.
The `-v` flag turns on the verbose output mode in `pip`.

Comment: I actually solved this problem. It was just Xcode being out of date. I am using Mac. Thanks for help though.